# Restrict No. Of Columns in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that shows the columns as per the data in the tables.
I need to restrict the table to show only 3 columns.I dont have to show the remaining columns in the SSRS table.

Note. I am not looking for page break here.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the columns by using the right click on the unwanted column.

Or you can add a new report instead of going through the reporting Wizard, it has only three columns by default.

Comment: Are the columns generated through a column group? If so this solution won't work.